# How to compare combobox value with items in listbox - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox, listbox

I have a combo box and a listbox.
All i want is, when i select a value(text) from the combobox to check if there is a same value(same text) at the listbox and if there is, then msgbox should display as "DATA FOUND"

i tried this code, but its not working

Dim i As Integer

```
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = ListBox1.ValueMember Then
            MsgBox("DATA FOUND")
        End If

    Next i
```

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using two properties with a different meaning for your comparison.
[SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an object (could be anything depending on how you have filled the combo, [ValueMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is just the name of a property to use as the actual value for the items in the ListBox.

However the two classes (ListBox and ComboBox) share the same pattern for storing their list items, so supposing that both are populated using a list of strings then your code could be

```
Dim curComboItem = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    If  curComboItem = ListBox1.Items(i).ToString() Then
        MsgBox("DATA FOUND")
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = ListBox1.ValueMember Then
```

should be

```
If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = ListBox1.Items(i) Then
```

Notice that 
    ComboBox1.SelectedItem
only works for items inside of the Collection. You can extend this to any text by the 
    .text
parameter.

P.D.

```
Next i '???
```

Answer (score 0):

Using real objects in your `ComboBox` and `ListBox` can often lead to better flexibility of your application.

For example, you have a car lot application, in which you have long list of available cars and you don't want to browse the entire list - you use ComboBox to select make and model, and do something with the items in your list box.

(in pseudo-code)

Your car object.

```
class Car
    ModelId
    ModelMake
    ModelName
    FullName = ModelMake & " " & ModelName
End Class

class AvailableCar Inherits Car
    IsOnTheLot
    VIN
    Price
    'etc
End Class
```

In your Form class

```
comboCarMakes.DataSource = GetListOfMakesOfCars() ' List of Car classes
comboCarMakes.ValueMember = "ModelId"
comboCarMakes.DisplayMember = "FullName" 

listAvbailableCars.DataSource = GetListOfAvailableCars() ' List of AvailableCar classes
listAvbailableCars.ValueMember = "VIN"
listAvbailableCars.DisplayMember = "FullName" 

Sub comboCarMakes_SelectedIndexChanged


    Dim car as Car = DirectCast(comboCarMakes.SelectedItem, Car)
    For i = 0 To listAvbailableCars.Items.Count - 1
        If  car.ModelId = DirectCast(listAvbailableCars.Items(i), AvailableCar).ModelId Then
            ' Do something
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Advantage - you have lots of information available immediately.